# Reduce total amount when remove in ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I have a ListView and a button. When I click on it, it will add a (name, price, quantity, total) and the total amount in my label, the problem is how can I reduce the total amount in the label when I remove the checked item in ListView

By the way, my data types for total and price are in the form not inside the button the inside of the button is the amount of price,total and calculations.

Here's the remove button for ListView

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var confirmation = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirmation",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (confirmation == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            for (int i = listView1.CheckedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ListViewItem itm = listView1.CheckedItems[i];
                listView1.Items[itm.Index].Remove();
                label5.Text = "0"; //label for total amount
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for adding a item in `ListView`

```
private void addItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView1.FindItemWithText("Cola");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Quantity", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        textBox2.Text = "";
    }
    else if (textBox2.Text == "0")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid Quantity", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else if (item != null)
    {
        price = 500;
        quantity = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        total = price * quantity;
        item.SubItems[2].Text = quantity.ToString();
        item.SubItems[3].Text = total.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = "";
        totalAll = total + total2;
        label5.Text = totalAll.ToString();
    }
    else if (item == null)
    {
        price = 500;
        quantity = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        total = price * quantity;
        String[] row = { label1.Text, price.ToString(), quantity.ToString(), total.ToString() };
        item = new ListViewItem(row);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        textBox2.Text = "";
        totalAll = total + total2;
        label5.Text = totalAll.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code that adds a listview item? so we can see where you're storing the the item's `total` property?

Comment: I got an error on your first answer, and i provided the code for add item please check it thanks!

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. This assumes that `totalAll` is a class level variable that can be accessed from the button code. If it's not, it should be.

Comment: yes the `totalAll` is class level variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're keeping a running total of all the items in the ListBox, you could just subtract the total of the item you're removing:

```
// Subtract selected item total from grand total
// This assumes that your 'totalAll` variable is a class-level double variable 
// and that the item total is stored in the `Text` property of itm.SubItems[3]
totalAll = totalAll - double.Parse(itm.SubItems[3].Text); 

label5.Text = totalAll.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks its working! but the value of the `label5.Text` is not resetting if i remove the item and re-add again the value stays

Comment: the value still stays when i remove and re-add again but its working on first remove

Comment: I can't tell if you're saying that re-adding an item doesn't add the total back again, or if removing an item the second time doesn't subtract the item total. You can set a breakpoint on the first line of code inside the 'add' or 'remove' block (whichever is giving you trouble) and then step through the code to see the flow. For example, in your `add` code, it does not show where `total2` gets set, but that code does not appear to add the current item total to the grand total.

Comment: here's my data types in class level variable `public static Double price, quantity, total, total2, totalAll;` so in `addItem_Click` "button" = total2 and `addItem1_Click` "button"  = total

Comment: it is subtracting the total amount in first remove of item but if i re-add a item again the value is still there, its like the `label5.Text` is saving a value? or is there a way to reset the value?

Comment: I mean if i remove the first and second row or remove all rows in `ListView` and re-add again the value stays

Comment: I think the line of code that should change is this one: `totalAll = total + total2;`. It's not clear what `total2` is, but the code should probably be: `totalAll = totalAll + total;`

Comment: Thanks a lot I've found the problem! its all working now

Answer (score 0):

After the loop, I would just set it to the current number of items:

```
if ( ...confirm... )
{
    for ( ... )
    {
    }

    label5.Text = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not reducing the total amount its just counting the remaining items, how can i reduce the total amount? example in list view: row 1 = (price = 300) row 2 = (price = 500) if i remove row 2 it will only display the price of row 1 in `label5.Text`